# what does echo ${1+"$@"} mean

Tags: linux, shell, erlang

From /usr/local/bin/erl

```
ROOTDIR=/usr/local/lib/erlang
BINDIR=$ROOTDIR/erts-5.9.1/bin
EMU=beam
PROGNAME=`echo $0 | sed 's/.*\///'`
export EMU
export ROOTDIR
export BINDIR
export PROGNAME
exec $BINDIR/erlexec ${1+"$@"}
```

I know "$@" meams arguments. But {1+"$@"} means what?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68484/what-does-1-mean-in-a-shell-script-and-how-does-it-differ-from

Comment: It's an anachronism. You can (and should) just use `"$@"` instead.

Comment: ...also, not quoting `$BINDIR` is a bug, as is not quoting `$0`, and the use of sed instead of a parameter expansion is damned silly. Don't treat this as code to be emulated.

Answer (score 4):

From IEEE Std 1003.1 (POSIX 2013), [Shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

```
${parameter:+[word]}
```

> Use Alternative Value. If parameter is unset or null, null shall be substituted; otherwise, the expansion of word (or an empty string if word is omitted) shall be substituted.

I.e., `${1+"$@"}` expands to the value of `"$@"`, the command line arguments, except when `$1` is not set, i.e. there are no command line arguments, in which case the expression expands to nothing. A simpler script that shows how this works is

```
echo '"' ${1+"$@"} '"'
```

If you store this in a file `test.sh` and run it, you get:

```
/tmp$ sh test.sh
" "
/tmp$ sh test.sh 1
" 1 "
/tmp$ sh test.sh 1 2
" 1 2 "
```

(The spaces at the begin and end come from `echo`.)

Comment: How is this different from `echo '"' $@ '"'`?

Comment: Magnus, extremely different -- `"$@"` uses the original word-splitting, whereas an unquoted `$@` acts like `$*`; and in `"$@"` the double quotes are syntactic, whereas in your example they're data.

Comment: Ah, then, I guess what I wanted to ask was, how is `${1+"$@"}` different from `"$@"`? This seems to have been answered by William Pursell.

Comment: ${parameter:+[word]} and ${1+"$@"}, why the ":" in the former does not appear in the latter？

Answer (score 4):

larsmans provides an explanation of the semantics, but doesn't clarify why `${1+"$@"}` is different than simply `"${@}"`.  In a properly behaving shell, "${@}" expands to nothing.  That is: `foo "$@"` should call `foo` with no arguments if "$@" is empty.  In an incorrectly behaving shell, `foo "$@"` will be invoked with one argument (the empty string).  Many historical shells expanded "$@" to the empty string rather than to nothing, but `${1+"$@"}` correctly expands to nothing.

Comment: ...to be clear, that's POSIX-noncompliant historical shells; there's no need to worry about that bug in a modern shell today.

Comment: Indeed, it seems this is a [workaround for the true Bourne shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68484/what-does-1-mean-in-a-shell-script-and-how-does-it-differ-from).